# Logical Notation in Anscombe's "Causality and Extensionality"

Tags: logic, anscombe

In "Causality and Extensionality," Anscombe writes thus:

Our argument uses the description of a class—say x̂(Gx · p), assuming G to be a respectable class-forming predicate. Let G be such that x̂(Gx) logically can’t be empty. Then x̂(Gx · p) is the same class as x̂(Gx) iff p is true. Also, the proposition saying that x̂(Gx · p) is the same class as x̂(Gx) is logically equivalent to p itself.

Does anyone know what this notation means?

Comment: This is Russell's class formation operator from *Principia* x̂(Gx):=the class of all x satisfying G. We would use set builder {x | G(x)} for the same purpose today. See. e.g. [Logical Form and the Development of Russell’s Logicism by Klement](https://people.umass.edu/klement/lf_development_russells_logicism.pdf).

Comment: The interchangeability of a class defined by a predicate and truth value with the truth value itself seems to me to be an instantiation of Tarski's T statement of the [semantic theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._E._M._Anscombe) where it is understood that proposition "P" is true if, and only if, P. Any more background?

Comment: Fantastic. For some reason, I am under the impression that the dot means "and", so that x̂(Gx · p) could be said to mean the same as { x | G(x) ∧ p}. Is this correct? (didn't see anything on this in an admittedly cursory glance at Klement)

Comment: Since Anscombe says right before the OP quote:"*The essential trick is to produce a designation of a  class or of an object, or an open sentence, which incorporates an independent proposition as a conjunct*", -  I'd say your impression is well gotten. *Principia* does use dot for conjunction, among other things, see [PM: Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica#Notation). And, as Wikipedia puts it, "*PM feels it necessary to create a peculiar notation "ẑ(φz)" that it calls a "fictitious object"*".